# Delete all rows that aren't in another table in SQLite

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

I have two tables (A and B).

I want to delete all the rows in Table B where B.1 isn't in Table A.2.

So I wrote this formula in sqlite:

```
DELETE FROM B 
WHERE 1 
IN 
 (SELECT * 
  FROM B 
  LEFT JOIN A 
  ON A.1=B.2 
  WHERE A.1 
  IS NULL)
```

But this returns this error:

```
only a single result allowed for a SELECT that is part of an expression
```

Could anyone give me a hand?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue for your example query is that an IN clause can not be used in conjunction with `SELECT *` when the `SELECT *` returns more than one column.  You need to specify the column...

### NOT IN

```
DELETE FROM B
 WHERE B.2 NOT IN (SELECT A.1
                     FROM A)
```

### NOT EXISTS

```
DELETE FROM B
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                     FROM A
                    WHERE A.1 = B.2)
```

SQLite doesn't support JOINs in DELETE statements, but you could also use:

```
DELETE FROM B
 WHERE B.2 IN (SELECT B.2
                 FROM B
            LEFT JOIN A ON A.1 = B.2
                WHERE A.1 IS NULL)
```

### Conclusion:

I don't have any performance statistics for SQLite, but the `NOT EXISTS` would be my choice because it returns true on the first time it's satisfied--very good for dealing with duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a typo somewhere in your question (maybe table B.2?), but I think what you want is:

```
DELETE FROM B WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM A WHERE A.1 = B.2)
```

Comment: Thanks, Ponies.  I've been busy, but hope to spend more time here this fall.